# Delete Item && Edit item for a DVWP

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a custom ListView web part and want to add three `LinkButton`s at the bottom of the web part.
How do I get the `SelectedItem` in custom `ListView` and edit/delete this.
I use this code for adding a new item

```
        onclick="javascript:NewItem('{$URL_New}', false);javascript:return false;"
```

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Designer, When your web part is selected, under Options Ribbon tab, you can enable Inline Editing so that edit/delete links appear for each record.

Comment: I have a custom listview webpart . I insert 3 hyperlink botton of this . I want edit/delete selected item.